# In angular2 this.fieldRef.nativeElement.focus(); is not working in IOS devices

Tags: angular

I am a newbie to angular2 and had made a component with template but on home page i need to set default focus on a input field i used

```
@ViewChild('keyword') // element reference to the keyword textbox.
public searchkeywordref: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.searchkeywordref.nativeElement.focus();
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);

}
```

```html
<section class="searchBlock">
<!-- index page -->
        <div class="searchSection">
                <div class="container">
                    <h2 class="text-center">Service made easy</h2>
                    <div class="selectbar clearfix">
                        <div class="inputBar businessSearchInput border-rt-search dropdown {{ (suggestions?.length > 0) ? 'open' : '' }}">
                            <input placeholder="Search Business" #keyword class="dropdown-toggle text-left" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" [(ngModel)]="searchKeyword" (ngModelChange)="keywordSuggestions()" (keydown)="arrowkeyLoc($event)" autofocus>
                        </div>                       
                        <div class="searchBtn clearfix customLoader" (click)="searchResult()">
                            
                            <button *ngIf="isloader == false" ><span></span> Search </button>
                            <button *ngIf="isloader == true" ><loaders-css [loader]="'ball-clip-rotate-multiple'" [loaderClass]="'customLoader-ball'"></loaders-css> </button>
                                                       
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    <!-- index page -->
</section>

<!--home component selector binding current location's latitude & longitude -->
    <app-home *ngIf="lat != null" [lat]="lat" [lng]="lng"></app-home>
<!-- home component selector -->
```

But it is not working in IOS devices.

Comment: Can you post your html?

Comment: @Hayden please check the updated question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try wrapping it in a `setTimeout` and running change detection manually again like so:

```
export class CustomComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
   constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectionRef){}
   
   ngAfterViewInit(){
      setTimeout(() => {
         this.searchkeywordref.nativeElement.focus();
         this.cd.detectChanges();
      }, 0)
  }
}
```